# Missing usable space on RAID5

Tags: storage, raid5

I have 3 drives, 4TB each, in a RAID5 setup. Usable space is 7.24 TB, all good & checks out. I use 5.5Tb and it reports 600Gb left. Maths does not checkout. I get an external drive and I move 5.5Tb of storage off the RAID5 drives an onto a separate drive and the RAID5 drives report usable space of 7.24 TB.

~1TB of space was missing on the RAID5 drives and I don't understand why. I'm guessing something messed up with calculating free space, and moving files around forced things to recalculated remaining space?

At the time...
I tied using df and it reported free space as 600GB (so ~1TB missing)
I tried du and it reported total used space as 5.5TB (so should be 1.74 TB remaining)
I tried lsof | grep deleted and restarted any processes using deleted files, no difference
Restarted several times

Is this common on RAID5 setups?
Is there something I can do differently if it happens again?

Info on system in use...

Device:
TNAS F5-221

uname -r
4.19.165+

cat /etc/os-release
NAME=Terra-Master Tnas
VERSION=3.x
ID=Tnas
VERSION_ID=2018.04.9
PRETTY_NAME="Tnas 2018.04.9"

Comment: Are you storing a few huge files or is it millions and millions of tiny files?

Comment: @Kusalananda mixture of both. Example of high number of files/folders is 19,310 Files in 2,261 Folders which makes up ~550Gb of the 5.5Tb in use.